# GWT JUnit: com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans-6.9, junit4

As my application gets broadened, I have decided to apply JUnit test so I can prevent NullPointerException
as much as possible especially in Activity & Place as well as RequestFactory.

However, I am trying to perform tests on ClientFactory, I have been able to pass arguments to JUnit like the
followijng:

gwt.test.jvmargs=-Xmx256M -Dgwt.args="-testBeginTimeout 5" -Dgwt.args="-prod" -Dgwt.args="-runStyle Manual:1"

When I ran the test, I am getting InternalCompilerException. Below is the error stack:

```
Validating newly compiled units
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/gwt-2.1.1/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/client/LogConfiguration.java'
      [ERROR] Line 77: The method addHandler(Handler) is undefined for the type Logger
[ERROR] Failed to create an instance of 'com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.JUnitHost' via deferred binding
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.translateException(JsVisitor.java:466)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:452)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:667)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:64)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:219)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:64)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:286)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsArrayAccess.traverse(JsArrayAccess.java:72)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:311)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBinaryOperation.traverse(JsBinaryOperation.java:108)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:509)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsExprStmt.traverse(JsExprStmt.java:37)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1002)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:48)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:43)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:423)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:98)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.generateJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:255)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.getJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:242)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.createNativeMethods(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:49)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.injectJsniMethods(CompilingClassLoader.java:1215)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1039)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.JUnitHost_Proxy.<clinit>(JUnitHost_Proxy.java:15)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.loadClassFromSourceName(ModuleSpace.java:654)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:458)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.<init>(GWTRunner.java:184)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunnerImplgecko1_8.<init>(GWTRunnerImplgecko1_8.java:6)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.io
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:479)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:465)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1011)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getClassFromBinaryName(CompilingClassLoader.java:236)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getClassFromBinaryOrSourceName(CompilingClassLoader.java:266)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getClassInfoFromClassName(CompilingClassLoader.java:288)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:146)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.getDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:930)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:105)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsNameRef.traverse(JsNameRef.java:121)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:450)
        ... 61 more
[ERROR] Failed to create an instance of 'com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner' via deferred binding
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.JUnitHost' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.<init>(GWTRunner.java:184)
        at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunnerImplgecko1_8.<init>(GWTRunnerImplgecko1_8.java:6)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
        ... 13 more
[ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner (see associated exception for details)
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[ERROR] Failed to load module 'org.opevel.projectname.JUnit' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.19) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.5.19 GTB7.1' at localhost:2034
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:434)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Will appreciate some assistance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The testing tools exposed by GWT's command line tools are not compatible with JUnit, resulting in the error:

> `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.io`

You have two options:

1. If the unit you are testing doesn't call `GWT.create()` (implicitly or explicitly) or otherwise depend on native Javascript, you can use JUnit as you would with any other project (i.e. from the command line: `java java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ...` [Here is some more info on JUnit testing in GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JUnit.html).
2. If the unit you are testing does somehow depend on native Javascript you need to use `GWTTestCase` which is [described in the GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html).

Consider looking into the [MVP Pattern](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) as one of its explicit goals is to make as much of an application as possible testable using JUnit (largely because it is *much* faster than tests based on `GWTTestCase`).

Comment: Thanks Jason. I do adopt MVP pattern using Activity and Place. It does really makes development maintenable but only to some degree. However, I was able to solve the problem by getting rid of restlet from my classpath. Thanks